# error when i try to load the rails console in 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I get the following error when i try to load the rails console in 3.1. why do i get this? am i doing something wrong?

```
/home/brettlee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/brettlee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/brettlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/brettlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/brettlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `require'
from /home/brettlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Bryan is right - just try installing libncurses & libreadline first, there's a good chance that'll work by itself. If that doesn't fly, you might need to do the whole ruby reinstall thing.

Really common error - it means you're missing some libraries necessary to run console.

[This guide](http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/2010/11/25/readline-error-with-rvm-and-rails-3.html) should show you how to fix it.

The short of it is, try installing libncurses & readline with the following command (I'm guessing from your directory structure you're using Ubuntu. If it's something else that doesn't use apt-get, change accordingy)

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev
ruby ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/readline/ext/extconf.rb
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/readline/ext/
sudo make
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to reinstall ruby 1.9.2 through rvm after installing the readline package. Don't uninstall the libncurses/readline packages installed through apt-get though - you'll still need 'em.

```
rvm package install readline
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
ruby ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/readline/ext/extconf.rb
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/readline/ext/
sudo make
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Per the post you linked to, the first three steps of removing and reinstalling ruby are (probably) unnecessary and definitely time consuming. Unless I remember incorrectly, it was my experience compiling 1.9.2-p290 that you just need to install `libncurses-dev` and `libreadline-dev`, run `extconf.rb`, then `make` and `sudo make install` (I believe you're missing that last step). Also, [backup on not needing to recompile Ruby](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/57-Solution-to-require-no-such-file-to-load-readline-LoadError-problem), although YMMV with RVM.

Comment: I did everything and now i get the "openssl" error. how can i install ruby with both readline and openssl?

Comment: Yep - another common one. sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby     Don't worry, Ruby gets a lot less headachey after the initial install.

Comment: @Rahul, you'll need to install libssl. Something like `sudo apt-get install openssl` should work, although the easiest way to find _all_ the dependencies you need is just to run `rvm_notes`. It provides a one-liner to install Ruby dependencies (many of which you'll want for compiling things on Linux generally). After that you'd `cd` to ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ext/openssl, run extconf.rb, make, sudo make install.

Comment: Erm, sorry, that's `rvm notes`.